# Pandas series: Truth Value of a Boolean is Ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas, series, calculated-columns

So I'm not sure why this works one way but not the other.

I have a column that calculates a value and compares it to a static column.

When I just compare those two have have the function print(column1>column2) I get a nice series of True/False values.

So it is working there, but when I try to then incorporate that same inequality for an if/else statement, it kicks off the following error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Why is that?

Here is the code:

```
def airportcheck(x1, y1):
    point1 = line(line1m, line1b, x1, y1)
    point2 = line(line2m, line2b, x1, y1)
    point3 = line(line3m, line3b, x1, y1)
    point4 = line(line4m, line4b, x1, y1)
    if point3>=y1:
        print(1)
    print(point3>y1)
    #if point1 > y1 and point3 > y1 and point4 < y1 and point2 < y1:
    #    return 1
    #else:
    #    return 0


df_data['Airport'] =(airportcheck(df_data['Pickup_longitude'], df_data['Pickup_latitude']))
```

Comment: Because a whole Series doesn't have a single True or False value.

Comment: So it's not vectorizing it like it does for everything else in the equation?

Comment: Yes, it's vectorizing it, but you haven't told it how you want a vector full of booleans to be treated. Sorry I can't give you more specific advice. I know (a bit of) Numpy, where this same issue occurs, but not Pandas.

Comment: No problem. Thanks. I was confused because it vectorized everything also nicely except for the when the if/else was introduced. I'll just try to use a pandas apply/lambda combo to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for `apply` or a lambda function - just use [`all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) to check the truthiness over each of your entire series.

```
if (point1 > y1).all() and \
   (point3 > y1).all() and \
   (point4 < y1).all() and \
   (point2 < y1).all():
    # ...
```